# VB.net telnet application

Tags: vb.net, telnet

An currently writing a vb.net application to send and receive information from a client via telnet.

Am using System.net.Sockets to do this.
I can send data great and get data back is ok.

So the Problem is in the command window after I telnet in to the server application, when i press the delete key the cursor moves back a character and doesn't delete the character, just over writes it and when I read the bytes in I get the deleted character and the ascii value for the delete key and then the replacement character.

I have seen another telnet application that shows the deletion of characters in the Command window.

Comment: I feel some code is missing here to show what you've done for the Telnet client, so others can learn from it and maybe also better find answers. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

1. There's quite a bit more to telnet than just sending data over a socket.  ([See RFC854](ftp://ftp.rfc-editor.org/in-notes/rfc854.txt))  If you're not implementing the protocol, then you're just using sockets.  Mixing telnet and non-telnet clients will mostly seem to work, but you'll get glitches here and there as one side or the other attempts to negotiate (whether intentionally, as a decent telnet client might, or unintentionally by sending a Telnet command byte).
2. If your telnet client is running in line mode (most *nix clients do; many Windows ones don't, but almost all can switch), then Delete and Backspace are handled locally, and the server only sees the final, edited line.  Note that this means the server doesn't see chars as you type them -- it receives a line at a time.